# iPhone - the apple crashes with releasing NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablearray

This is my code using NSMutableArray.

```
- (void) put:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value
{
    Element *element = [[[Element alloc] initWith:key strValue:value] autorelease];
    if (self.map) {
        [map addObject:element];
    }
    else {
        map = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:element];
    }
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    if (map) {
            [map release];
    }

    [super dealloc];
}
```

My apple crashes at line:[map release];

What's wrong in my code?

I tried releasing 'map' as follow.

```
- (void) put:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value
{
    Element *element = [[[Element alloc] initWith:key strValue:value] autorelease];
    if (self.map) {
        [map addObject:element];
    }
    else {
        map = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:element];
        [map release]
    }

}
```

Then the apple does not crash.
How solve this problem?

Comment: Buy a peach. Apple's are known to crash.

Comment: @MiRAGe: I'd really like to submit your comment to the daily "Most Useless Comment"-competition.

Comment: I'd argue MiRAGe's comment is the second most useless comment posted here. (And now I've commented, it might be in third place!)

Comment: lolzz... i have heard a lots of times that "my app crashes , etc.", but this is really somethig unique ... "my apple crashes"... hehe.. cant stop my laughter

Comment: I take your comments all as a compliment. Saying 'my apple crashes' might be the funniest thing I ever heard. Mind you I have a low standard on humor. P.S: 'the apple works properly at all' is also in my top 10. This has nothing to do with language barriers, so laughter is allowed. Right? I'll shut up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If map is a retained/copied property do `self.map=...` to retain it. `[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:element]` returns an autoreleased object that needs to be retained.

Comment: Thanks for your early advice. The apple works properly at all.

Answer (score 3):

The `arrayWithObject:` method returns an autoreleased object; you need to either retain the array:

```
map = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:element] retain];
```

or use the `initWithObject:` method:

```
map = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObject:element];
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd use the second one - it's very slightly more efficient because it doesn't add the object to the autorelease pool.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the convenience initializer `arrayWithObject`, which has an implicit `autorelease`. You can't `release` an autoreleased object.